# Место частицы "не"

Tags: частица-не, сказуемые

Правильно ли употреблять частицу "не" не перед глаголом-связкой в составном именном сказуемом, а перед причастием (или другим типом именной части), чтобы подчеркнуть, что именно к нему относится отрицание?

"Они были не связаны..."  вместо "Они не были связаны...".

То же самое в составном глагольном сказуемом: частица "не" перед инфинитивом, а не перед вспомогательным глаголом.

"Если ты действительно хочешь ничего не делать..."

Answer (score 2):

Грамматической проблемы нет, а стилистически это вполне оправдано в случае, когда тем же глаголом-связкой вводится противопоставление без отрицания, явное или подразумеваемое.

> Они были не связаны(, а забаррикадированы плитой).
>
> Если ты действительно хочешь ничего не делать, а только деньги
>   получать, то ты бездельник.

Comment: А что значит "противопоставление без отрицания"? В первом предложении в противопоставлении отрицание как раз таки есть.